# How to plot accuracy with a trained model

Tags: python, tensorflow, metrics

I have a `Tensorflow` model already trained in my notebook, and I want to plot accuracy and loss after that.

Here is my code:

```py
myGene = trainGenerator(2,'/content/data/membrane/train','image','label',
                       data_gen_args,save_to_dir = None)
model = unet()
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('unet_membrane.hdf5', 
                             monitor='loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
model.fit_generator(myGene,steps_per_epoch=2000,
                    epochs=5,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
```

Is there a way to plot anything?
Because I tried with `matplotlib` and it doesn't work.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history['loss'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
history = model.fit_generator(myGene,
              steps_per_epoch=2000,
              epochs=5,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
```

and then, for plotting:

```
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
```

Comment: Oh thanks I forgot to store my training in a variable. Thanks it worked fine :)